# jquery.val() vs underlying element value performance

Tags: jquery, performance, dom

I have a simple performance question.

Which one is better

```
var elem = jQuery("#idOfMyElem"), y;
if (elem.length) {
    y = elem.val();
    // y = elem[0].value;
}
```

Which one performs better? The elem.val() or elem[0].value;

Comment: Performance questions should ALWAYS be evaluated by running a test.  Use jsPerf.com to construct a relevant test.  Also, if you want the best performance, avoid jQuery in your first line.  Use `document.getElementById()` instead because that's probably an event bigger difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-val-test) is a simple test.
According to it, `y = elem.val()` is ~90% slower than `y = elem[0].value`

Answer (score 4):

This one:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('idOfMyElem'), y;

if (elem) {
    y = elem.value;
}

$(elem).on('click', function() { ... })
```

Comment: hi thanks but i need the jquery elem cause i am going to use it for other stuff. Like adding event listener to it.

Comment: Then wrap it later -> $(elem).

Comment: @user578635 - performancewise, when getting an element by an ID, you'll probably never notice the difference, and sticking with jQuery all the way is often a good idea to make the code more readable and easier to understand later. Same goes for using the native value and val(), the difference is minescule, so do what you think is more readable.